# SQL select statement returning wrong data (where clause using <>)

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

Could someone please help me with the following code.  It is returning results even with the use of <> which I thought would exclude things.  I am not familiar with sql at all and would appreciate any and all help.  Thanks in advance.

```
    SELECT k109.keyvaluechar as [Transaction Number], k3257.keyvaluechar as [Fund Name], k4666.keyvaluechar as [Fund ID], k4667.keyvaluechar as [Investor Legal Name], k4638.keyvaluechar as [Transaction Type], k4740.keyvaluecurr as [Cash Transaction Amount], k4701.keyvaluedate as [Effective Date], lc.lifecyclename as [Life Cycle], lcs.statename as [Queue], k4795.keyvaluechar as [Missing Document]
FROM hsi.itemdata id
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem109 k109 on k109.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem3257 k3257 on k3257.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem4666 k4666 on k4666.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem4667 k4667 on k4667.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem4638 k4638 on k4638.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem4740 k4740 on k4740.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem4701 k4701 on k4701.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.keyitem4795 k4795 on k4795.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.itemlc ilc on ilc.itemnum = id.itemnum
    LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
    JOIN hsi.lifecycle lc on lc.lcnum = lcs.scope
          and (lc.lifecyclename = 'Client Transactions'
          or lc.lifecyclename = 'NEW IS Additional Subscription'
          or lc.lifecyclename = 'NEW IS New Subscription'
          or lc.lifecyclename = 'NEW IS Redemption'
          or lc.lifecyclename = 'NEW IS Transfer')
WHERE 
    id.status = 0 AND
    id.institution = 13 AND
        (lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Distribution' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Initiate' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Notifications' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - FTP Process' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Import FTP Docs') 
order by lc.lifecyclename, 
    CASE 
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Pending/Issue' THEN 1
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - SEI Review' THEN 2
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Missing Documents' THEN 3
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Complete' THEN 4
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - 1st Client Review' THEN 5
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - 2nd Client Review' THEN 6
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Rejected' THEN 7
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Additional Subscription - Review Document' THEN 8
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Additional Subscription - Archive' THEN 9
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'New Subscription - Review Document' THEN 10
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'New Subscription - Archive' THEN 11
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'New Subscription - FATCA Follow-Up' THEN 12
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Redemption - Review Document' THEN 13
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Redemption - Holdback' THEN 14
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Redemption - Archive' THEN 15
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Redemption - FATCA Follow-Up' THEN 16
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Transfer - Review Document' THEN 17
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Transfer - Archive' THEN 18
    WHEN lcs.statename = 'Transfer - FATCA Follow-Up' THEN 19
    ELSE 21
end,
    k109.keyvaluechar asc, k3257.keyvaluechar asc
```

Comment: Your boolean logic is wrong

Comment: `(a <> 1 OR a <> 2)` will always be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about this chunk of code

```
id.institution = 13 AND
        (lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Distribution' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Initiate' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Notifications' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - FTP Process' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Import FTP Docs')
```

It would be because you are using not equals in an or statement. That means no matter what lcs.statename is, the boolean returned by the bracketed segment will always be true because even if the statement is 'Client Transactions - Distribution' it is not 'Client Transactions - Initiate' so that or chain will be satisfied and return true. Essentially your statement looks like this `id.institution = 13 AND true`.

You want it to return false if its not any of those strings listed or do you want it to return true if its not one of those things

Either way you should switch all of the <> to =. This will check to see if the statement matches any of those strings. This will return true if it does find a match. If you want it to return false then add a not before the bracket to reverse it.

```
id.institution = 13 AND NOT
        (lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Distribution' AND
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Initiate' AND
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Notifications' AND
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - FTP Process' AND
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Import FTP Docs')
```

Comment: I changed to this according to what you have said this should work correct?
 'id.institution = 13 AND NOT
 (lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Distribution' OR
 lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Initiate' OR
 lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Notifications' OR
 lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - FTP Process' OR
 lcs.statename = 'Client Transactions - Import FTP Docs') '

Comment: I believe you want it to return true if it is within those strings which means you don't want to include the not. Also for some reason what you wrote there is not what I wrote above. Note the where you wrote OR I have written AND.

Answer (score 1):

```
(lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Distribution' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Initiate' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Notifications' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - FTP Process' OR
        lcs.statename <> 'Client Transactions - Import FTP Docs')
```

in above part replace all OR with AND

Comment: Thank you.  This doesn't really make to much sence to me as it is pulling info of a doc that can only be in one of the 5 mentioned queues at one time.  I did test it though and it seems to work well.  Thanks so much for the quick answer!